# Erro ao tentar passar uma coleção ordenada para uma View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Estou tentando passar para a `View` uma coleção ordenada, porém estou sempre tendo o mesmo erro:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'TituloDeCortesia'

A única forma que estou conseguindo rodar o meu código com sucesso é usando a seguinte linha:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TituloDeCortesia, new SelectList(new[] { "Dr.", "Mr.", "Ms.", "Mrs." }), String.Empty)
```

Porém, sem ordenação. Neste exemplo eu ordenei manualmente, mas no caso de listagem maiores e dinâmicas, esta solução que encontrei não resolveria.

Segue o meu código abaixo:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Adicionar()
{
    List< string > ListaTitulo = new List< string > { "Ms.", "Dr.", "Mrs.", "Mr." };
    ListaTitulo.Sort();
    ViewBag.TituloDeCortesia = new SelectList(ListaTitulo);
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@model MvcModeloEmpresa.Dominio.Empregado
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Adicionar";
}

<h2>Adicionar</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Empregado</legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmpregadoID)

        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrimeiroNome)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PrimeiroNome)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrimeiroNome)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UltimoNome)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UltimoNome)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UltimoNome)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Titulo)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Titulo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Titulo)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TituloDeCortesia)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("TituloDeCortesia", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TituloDeCortesia)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataNascimento)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataNascimento)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataNascimento)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataContratacao)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataContratacao)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataContratacao)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Endereco)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Endereco)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cidade)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cidade)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cidade)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Regiao)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Regiao)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Regiao)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CodigoPostal)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CodigoPostal)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodigoPostal)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pais)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pais)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pais)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TelefoneResidencial)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TelefoneResidencial)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TelefoneResidencial)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Extensao)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Extensao)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Extensao)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notas)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notas)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notas)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Salvar" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Voltar", "Index")
</div>
```

**Erro Apresentado**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Testei seu código aqui e funcionou perfeitamente. Está entrando na action `Adicionar` ao debugar?

Comment: Quando eu seleciono um item e vou submeter os dados, tenho o erro da imagem que eu inseri no final da minha pergunta.

Comment: Coloque na sua pergunta todo e qualquer informação do trafego do controller para view (Código completo)

Comment: Cezar, você quer que eu coloque todo o código da minha View? Como faço para ver o tráfego do meu método de controlador?

Comment: Como disse o @Cezar, seu código está correto. Olhe um exemplo funciona aqui (https://dotnetfiddle.net/8wwRPR). Qual versão do Asp.Net MVC você está utilizando?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

eu descobri o erro no meu código. Eu estava usando campo oculto em uma View de inserção de dados que não há necessidade. Ao perceber o erro e excluir, eu consegui passar uma coleção diretamente pelo meu método de controlador **Adicionar**

```html
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmpregadoID)
```

Comment: Não existe relação entre ordenar os dados em uma view com um campo `hidden` em seu método adicionar. Provavelmente você se expressou mal em sua pergunta, onde sua resposta não resolve o erro.

Answer (score 2):

Essas duas formas como exemplo abaixo são corretas:

```
@Html.DropDownList("TituloDeCortesia", String.Empty)
@Html.DropDownList("TituloDeCortesia", (SelectList)ViewBag.TituloDeCortesia)
```

Ou seja, o seu código está correto pelo que está na questão, o que deve estar acontecendo é outro tipo de erro de não passagem da informação corretamente pelo ViewBag.

Outra forma

```
public ActionResult Adicionar()
{

    IList<SelectListItem> Lista = new List<SelectListItem>();

    Lista.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Ms.", Value = "Ms." });
    Lista.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Dr.", Value = "Dr." });
    Lista.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Mrs.", Value = "Mrs." });
    Lista.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Mr.", Value = "Mr." });

    ViewBag.ListaTitulo = Lista;

    return View();
}
```

View: (Somente aquele trecho)

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Titulo de Cortesia")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.TituloDeCortesia, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ListaTitulo)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TituloDeCortesia)
</div>
```

Observe que o Label eu tive que colocar diretamente nesse caso, por favor teste!!!

Comment: Ceza, já tentei das duas formas e apresenta o mesmo erro.

Comment: @KellySoares, você está fazendo alguma coisa errada, eu precisaria ver na sua pergunta toda a view e todo o seu controller, qualquer coisa cole também no www.pastebin.com

Comment: Editei a minha pergunta colocando a minha View completa.

Comment: @KellySoares coloquei outra forma pra ti testar ai por favor!

Comment: Cezar, ainda continua com erro como se eu tivesse usando um ViewData tentando buscar uma chave: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'TituloDeCortesia'.

Comment: Olha realmente o problema particular, porque, todas essas formas estão corretas inclusive o @Randrade criou um exemplo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8wwRPR e funciona perfeitamente !!! Qual versão do seu ASP.NET, Qual Visual Studio é (2010, 2015) etc ... ?

Comment: Eu uso o Visual Studio 2013 e o ASP.NET MVC 4.

Comment: Ceza, eu editei a minha pergunta logo no início. Eu inseri uma forma que encontrei para funcionar o código, mas não consegui colocar ordenação. Será que esta forma fica mais fácil de entender o problema ou tentar ordenar essa lista?

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TituloDeCortesia, new SelectList(new[] { "Dr.", "Mr.", "Ms.", "Mrs." }.OrderBy(x => x).ToList()), String.Empty) `

Tente assim

Comment: Cezar, funcionou. Por enquanto vou deixar a minha pergunta em aberto para ver se alguém consegue descobrir o problema que não está dando certo de passar uma coleção através de um método de controller. Obrigada pela ajuda!

Comment: @KellySoares, está parecendo que tu vai ter que instalar novamente o visual studio ou então formatar seu PC. Talvez seja isso.

Comment: Ceza, analisando o meu código descobri o erro, eu digitei toda a minha view sem usar o Scaffolding, com isso, a possibilidade de erros é um pouco maior, o que aconteceu comigo. Ao escrever o código acabei incluindo a linha @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmpregadoID), essa view é para inserção de dados, então não é necessário usar campos ocultos.